# How to exclude printed long path using python in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hi can I setup my python configuration for simple code

> print("yo")

so it just prints 'yo' and it does not spit out this long path in my terminal every time ...

[image]

Currently, my configuration in visual studio code is:
[image]

Comment: Maybe because you are using the debug console?

Comment: Interesting. Actually in the debug console, it shows like I want with just the output. How do I make it show that by default instead of showing the terminal window which has that long path?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Figured it out. I had to add...

> "console": "none"

to my configuration